# Converting SQL with Group By and Having to Entity Framework query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, group-by, having-clause

Thanks for your help on my need to convert sql to entity framework query with group by and having clauses...

```
SELECT EIC
FROM [HRIS].dbo.[tappServiceRecord] A
GROUP BY EIC HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var items = from log in context.tappServiceRecord                           
            group log by log.EIC into grouped where grouped.Count()>1
            select grouped.Key
```

Hope this will work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
var res = _context.tappServiceRecord
              .GroupBy(x => x.EIC)
              .Where(x => x.Count(y => y) > 1)
```